# How do I display the count value of the results from one column in a new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This stored procedure returns two values but it repeats multiple times.

[image: 1]

I am trying to get the count value of PLTGRN so that it shows up in a new column like in this image:

[image: 2]

My code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[GreenTire_Fits_In_Press]
    @Press varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT FAC,PLTGRN
    FROM [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work] cosw WITH (nolock)
    INNER JOIN [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[v_Curing_Tooling] CURE WITH (Nolock) ON Cure.MLDNBR = Cosw.MOLD
    WHERE Cosw.FAC = @Press
END
```

I tried adding `COUNT(PLTGRN)` in the select statement to the code above but that throws this error :

[image: error]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Said error is telling you the problem though.

Comment: Also, why are you using `NOLOCK`? With respect, I doubt you know what it *really* does, so you should **not** be using it. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `GROUP BY` :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[GreenTire_Fits_In_Press]
@Press varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
Select PLTGRN , COUNT(*) QTY
FROM [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work] cosw with (nolock)
Inner Join [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[v_Curing_Tooling] CURE with (Nolock)
On Cure.MLDNBR=Cosw.MOLD
Where Cosw.FAC=@Press
GROUP BY PLTGRN
End
```

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` is used with a `GROUP BY` clause. The aggregate functions summarize the table data. Once the rows are divided into groups, the aggregate functions are applied in order to return just one value per group. It is better to identify each summary row by including the `GROUP BY` clause in the query result.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[GreenTire_Fits_In_Press]
    @Press varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT FAC,PLTGRN, COUNT(PLTGRN)
    FROM [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work] cosw WITH (nolock)
    INNER JOIN [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[v_Curing_Tooling] CURE WITH (Nolock) ON Cure.MLDNBR = Cosw.MOLD
    WHERE Cosw.FAC = @Press
    GROUP BY FAC, PLTGRN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

-- you are missing group by and the part of the query to get count

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[GreenTire_Fits_In_Press]
@Press varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
Select FAC,PLTGRN, count(*)
FROM [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work] cosw with (nolock)
Inner Join [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[v_Curing_Tooling] CURE with (Nolock)
On Cure.MLDNBR=Cosw.MOLD
Where Cosw.FAC=@Press
Group By FAC,PLTGRN
End
```